# how do I implement content security policy in safari extension

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy, safari-extension

I am getting following error 
Refused to load
 https://plus.google.com/_/favicon?domain_url=https://idmsa.apple.com/appleauth/auth/signin?widgetKey=83545bf919730e51dbfba24e7e8a78d2&locale=en_US&font=sf&iframeId=24f64667-08f1-4ffb-ac10-4bda573c8ed7 because it does not appear in the img-src directive of the Content Security Policy.

> Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading
>   'https://idmsa.apple.com/appleauth/auth/signin?widgetKey=83545bf919730e51dbfba24e7e8a78d2&locale=en_US&font=sf&iframeId=24f64667-08f1-4ffb-ac10-4bda573c8ed7':
>   'ALLOW-FROM https://www.icloud.com' is not a recognized directive. The
>   header will be ignored.

Comment: guys if u can't answer at least don't down vote ..

Comment: The X-Frame-Options error is not relevant to the question. Are you trying to ask two different questions?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a local copy of the image in your extension, rather than hot-linking a remote image.  It appears Safari’s CSP rules for extensions doesn’t allow remote images the way you’re using them